# Rails Calendar - Showing 7 <tds> per row

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, calendar, html-table, erb

I am trying to build a calendar in my rails application and link the calendar dates to my `article_params` in order to see articles from a particular day.

I originally tried `datepicker`, but after I learned that I can't pass the JavaScript values to a controller, I decided to create my own calendar.

```
<% @current_date = Date.new(@year, @month, Time.now.day) %>
<% @start = @current_date.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week %>
<% @end = @current_date.end_of_month.end_of_week %>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><%= @months[Time.now.month - 1] %></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% (@start..@end).each_slice(7) do |d| %>
      <% d.each do |da| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= da.day %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please allow me to explain my code.

I first created an `instance variable` to store the current date. Because weeks start and end on Sundays, I created two more instance variables, for the start and end of the calendar month.

My `@months` variable is an instance variable that I added to my controller. It stores the names of the months.

For every week, I cut the range `@start..@end` into slices of 7. For every slice of 7 dates, I want to put all elements in that slice in their own table row.

Current Output

```
29
30
31
1
2
..
31
1
```

Expected Output

```
29 30 31 1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8  9  10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30 31 1
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are declaring a `tablerow` inside of a loop. That is why the results are all shown on their each line.

Change this

```
<% d.each do |da| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= da.day %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

To this

```
<tr>
  <% d.each do |da| %>
    <td><%= da.day %></td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

Now, each slice will have its own line